# Macro to fill cells based on conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

New user to Excel Macro's here but need to get this task done.

I was wondering how I would possibly go about filling cells with a set number based on a couple of conditions.

I have a spreadsheet that contains a 'score' column and a 'status' column, I was looking to filter the results of my spreadsheet so that only the rows with the  status called 'current' appear and that of those rows that appear, if the 'score' cell is empty for that particular row it fills it with the number 10.

I don't want for the rows that were filtered out to be removed, simply that they aren't involved in this process of filling in with the number 10.

If anyone can help that would be amazing.

Thanks very much and apologies in advance if I have not explained this very well !

Comment: I don't think anyone is just going to write you some code, you need to ask a specific question, and show some research effort, what have you tried, what's working, what isn't etc

Answer (score 1):

- Enable autofilter
- Filter by status = 'current'
- Filter by score = {empty}
- Insert 10 in some (filtered empty) cell
- Select this cell, Ctrl-C
- Select all empty filtered cells, Ctrl-V
- Disable autofilter
- Profit!